# docker compose browser tests skipped in azure pipeline, work fine on local

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-pipelines

I was running this `docker-compose` file in azure pipeline fine. But recently I observed that tests are skipped and I see this below error. I have seen same error on local before when browser instances are not correctly opened in local docker

However this time local is working fine using `docker-compose` and tests are running but when same  `docker-compose` file and test code is run in azure pipeline, I get this

```
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.test.support.Global.<init>(Global.java:29)
```

How do I debug docker in azure pipeline. Is there anything obvious that has changed recently that is causing this in azure pipeline.

my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.141.59-20210607
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "65299:4444"

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59-20210607
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 4

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox:3.141.59-20210607
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 4
```

azure pipeline.yml

```
trigger:
- master
resources:
- repo: self
variables:
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and Push image
  jobs:
   - job: Build
     displayName: Build and Push
     pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
     steps:
     - task: DockerCompose@0
       displayName: open browser instances
       inputs:
         containerregistrytype: 'Container Registry'
         dockerRegistryEndpoint: Dockerhub
         dockerComposeFile: '**/docker-compose.yml'
         action: 'Run a Docker Compose command'
         dockerComposeCommand: 'up -d'
         detached: true

     - task: Maven@3
       inputs:
         mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
         mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
         jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
         publishJUnitResults: true
         testResultsFiles: '**/target/cucumber.html'
         goals: 'clean verify -P acceptanceTests -e'
         
     - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
       displayName: Publish cucumber report
       inputs:
         pathToPublish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/s/target/cucumber-report/
         artifactName: 'cucumber.html'

     - task: PublishCucumberReport@1
       inputs:
         jsonDir: ./target/cucumber-report/
         outputPath: ./target/
```

When I see output of `docker-compose` task in pipeline , it shows that each browser is created fine

```
Starting: open browser instances
==============================================================================
Task         : Docker Compose
Description  : Build, push or run multi-container Docker applications. Task can be used with Docker or Azure Container registry.
Version      : 0.198.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
.....
.....
Creating selenium-hub ... done
.....
Creating myrepoName_chrome_3  ... done
Creating myrepoName_chrome_1  ... done
Finishing: open browser instances
```

I am using this in my tests to direct tests to docker-hub

`String hubURL = "http://localhost:65299/wd/hub";`

this works fine on local and I am expecting it to work fine in pipeline also